# How do I get Scons to remove unused source files from a variant directory

Tags: scons, auto-generate

I have a generated file from all of my sources, and the source generator uses a glob.  Since I use variant directories to build, all (and only) the source that is in this build should placed in the variant directory so I pointed the glob at that dir to scrape from. When I remove a file from the build, this fails as the .c file I removed is still in the variant dir from a previous build. Clean does not remove sources copied into variants, so even clean builds don't work, I have to remove all the directory (or at least *.c) to get a good build again.  Is there a way I can either: get scons to remove the extra sources, get a list of the no-longer needed sources so I can remove them pre-generation, or .....

I can not easily change the generator to take a list of files, tho that is the obvious 'best' solution.

SConstruct

```
VariantDir('build','src')
Command('generated.h', ['src1.c','src2.c'], 'python scrape_sources $TARGET.dir')
```

scrape_sources

```
import glob
import sys

f = open('generated')
f.write(','.join(glob.glob(sys.args[1]+'*.c'))
f.close()
```

When I remove src2.c from the list, the source file is still in `build` from the previous run and thus scanned. I want a way to nicely remove the sources no longer in the build.

Comment: It is still a bit unclear what you're trying to do. A `variant dir` is usually for storing your *built* files, not your sources. Please show an example SConstruct that demonstrates the issue at hand. Are you using , or at least aware of, the "duplicate=0" option?

Comment: why not just glob all the c files in the variant dir and use python to remove them at the beginning of your SConstruct? (Not using SCons, just plain python). Then SCons might repopulate the variant dir but not rebuild if not necessary?  Of course a runnable example would be helpful..

Comment: I am aware of duplicate=0, but then I would have several source dirs to scan, and there are files in each of those that I don't want in the generated file (for other variants). duplicate=1 seemed like a good way to get just the files I needed.

Comment: I could undo scons caching of the source files every time, I was hoping for a more elegant solution.